# Geiger tube counts-per-minute Poissonian, but counts-per-hour not. Why?

Tags: radiation, statistics, randomness

I am testing a Geiger tube and counting its pulses. Because the pulses are random, I expect the **counts-per-minute** (cpm) to follow a Poisson distribution. That's indeed what I found:

mean cpm = 38.39
variance of cpm = 39.21

Mean and variance are roughly the same, a signature of Poisson distribution.  Below is the plot, blue dots being the theoretical Poisson probabilities:

[image: Counts per minute]

However, **counts-per-hour** (cph) do not follow this pattern:

mean cph = 2303.69
variance of cph = 3496.63

With the plot below, blue line being the theoretical *normal* distribution:

[image: Counts per hour]

My question is, why does CPM follow a Poisson distribution but CPH does not? I suppose a Geiger tube should give random pulses on an hourly scale, right? When does a Poisson distribution "transition" to a Normal distribution?

(In light of some early responses) The data that makes up the above plots spans nearly two weeks, i.e. 18653 minutes and 310 hours. And I don't see any evidence that the counts vary by time of the day.

Comment: More details of the experiment would be useful. Perhaps some parameter is varying in time. Have you plotted a time series?

Comment: I did not plot a time series per se, but I did plot CPM against minute-of-day. And I don't see any pattern suggesting that the counts depend on time of the day. In other words, everything seems very random to me. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your counts per hour data is under-sampled. That is, you don't have enough data to faithfully reconstruct the expected Poissonian distribution. My guess is if you get more data points the CPH data histogram will begin to look more Poissonian.

Remember you're data does not represent the underlying probability distribution. Your data is a *realization* of the underlying probability distribution. As your data set becomes larger the distribution of your data (i.e. the *realization*) becomes a better and better approximation to the underlying distribution.

In the OP you calculate the mean and variances of your datasets. Recall that these are your "estimated" means and variances of the underlying probability distribution based on your dataset. It is actually possible to calculate an estimated variance (or uncertainty) on your estimate of the variance of the underlying distribution. That is, you can calculate your uncertainty (due to finite sample size) in your estimates of the mean and variance. My guess is that if you do this for your first data set you will find a relatively small uncertainty in the mean and variance, but if you do this for the second data set you will find a relatively larger uncertainty in the mean and variance. If everything works out right, you hopefully find that with ~1 sigma uncertainty, your estimate of the mean and variance are in fact consistent with the CPH distribution being Poissonian. But there's no guarantee that this is the case, and the best approach, if you really need to observe the Poissionian nature of the CPH distribution, would be to take more data.

Comment: The observed variance-to-mean ratio after 310 samples is about 1.52. That sounds implausibly high to me, but I admit that I don't know how to calculate the p-value or any confidence intervals here, so I could be totally wrong.

Comment: One could easily write code to simulate a Poissonian data set with similar parameters to determine if my "under-sampling" hypothesis is correct. The time-varying parameter suggestion from @JohnDoty was also a good hypothesis.

Comment: I am in a home setting. On a practical level, finding the mean is all I need. Knowing the distributions is a matter of curiosity. I can make a software simulation to see how a Poissonian CPM may add up to CPH, and will definitely take more samples. Thanks everyone.